# Check for a value in JSON returned in a REST endpoint

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

Im kinda new to React-native (and javascript) and I'm struggling to do this.

I have an api that has a users

https://api.example.com/users/

And I want it to check if the api returns a value when I hit an endpoint

https://api.example.com/users/{userName}

So something like this :

```
async function getUsersFromApi(userName) {
      try {
         let response = await 
         fetch('https://api.example.com/users/'+userName);
         let responseJson = await response.json();

         //if endpoint returns response
         // alert("endpoint exists")

       } catch(error) {
            console.error(error);
       }
      }
```

The part I wrote in comments was the part I was struggling with. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Loop through the array items in the response and check the "username" property of each object until you find it. Do you know how to use a for loop in JS?

Comment: Hmmm, I realised I posted an inappropriate example. I'm using my own api that I don't want to expose publicly. in this case, there is no array of users. I want to query the url  example.api.com/users/{userName}. If the url doesn't hit anything valid, it returns a 403, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [response.ok](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) property will tell you whether the request was successful and this is the usual way to determine whether a resource exists or not. If a user with the given `username` does not exist, the REST API should return a [404 error](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5), which will cause `response.ok` to be `false`.

```
const response = await fetch('https://api.example.com/users/'+userName);
const userExists = response.ok;
```

Note that if you are not going to use the response body at all, it is more appropriate to do a [HEAD](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) request. This instructs the server that it should not return a response body and skip any related computation that would have then been wasted. Thus the request is more efficient in both time and bandwidth.

```
const response = await fetch('https://api.example.com/users/'+userName. {
    method : 'GET'
});
const userExists = response.ok;
```

---

#### Edit: answer to original question below

Assuming you have a `users` array, you should use [Array#some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to loop through it and determine whether one of the objects in it has a username field that matches the `username` given to your function.

```
const userExists = users.some((user) => {
    return user.username === username;
});
console.log(userExists); // true or false
```

If, on the other hand, you need to return that user object rather than a boolean, you should use [Array#find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead.

```
const user = users.find((user) => {
    return user.username === username;
});
console.log(user); // user object or undefined
```

In the case of `find()`, be sure to handle the case where the user is not found and it returns undefined. If you're not careful, you may end up accessing a property on `undefined`, which will throw an error.

Comment: HI seth, sorry, I updated my post, I gave a bad example. I am using a custom api that i don't want to expose. I want to fetch 'api.example.com/users/{username} and see if it returns a Json response. If it does, I want to open an alert. If it returns a 404, I want it to open an alert saying "404 error"

Comment: I updated my answer to show how you can detect whether the server thinks a user exists. If you need more detail in a specific area, let me know.